# Impossible to go into Careers profile settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

From the other day I cannot access the Profile Settings page anymore inside the careers profile page .

It is a bug I was used to access that page ...

Is it only my problem or is it for everyone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We took a look and realized that we had, in fact, inadvertently broken that button. It is working now though you may need to refresh the page that the button is on before it will work as expected.

Please report back if you encounter any further problems, and thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: The issue is now solved, Thanks.